# Width and Height of Graphic Device not exact

Tags: r, graphics

I'm trying to produce a couple of textboxes with R that I can insert in Powerpoint (thereby circumventing the missing serial letter implementation in MS PP)

The issue that I have is that the specified width and height that i specify for the graphics device in R are not respected, once I import my device in PP.

To give you an example:

```
win.metafile("fig/text.wmf", height = unit(c(4.51),"cm"), width = unit(c(10.51),"cm"), pointsize = 9)
grid.text(x = 0, y = 1, just = c("left", "top"), label = "Test", gp = gpar(cex = 2))
dev.off()
```

produces my metafile. Once I import it to Powerpoint, the size is not **c(4.51,10.51)** anymore, but **c(15.31,35.61)**.

This is true for all other graphic devices (and not only if I import it into PP, but in general) as well.

Anyone has an explanation as why the device does not have the specified size?

Cheers, Hanno

Comment: And without importing in PowerPoint? What is the size of the file?

Comment: Windows Picture Manager tells me it has a size of 299*129 Pixels (Maybe the pixel conversion is somehow the reason)?